# Store specific value from csv into variable using powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this

```
"NumberofNullAsOfDates"
"0"
```

I would like to check if there is a 0 or any other value there. This is currently the powershell code I have but it doesn't seem to work out so well.

```
$testNum = @()
$testNum += Import-Csv craneAudit.csv
$testNum[1]
```

How could I make this work so that $testNum only contains "0" (without quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the value to int:

```
$intValue = [int]$testNum[1]
```